# Z and Y coordinates are swapped, regardless of the transform orientation?

Tags: coordinates, axis

Whenever I try to resize an object locked to Y axis, it resizes what used to be Z axis. I cycled through all of the transform orientations, but the Z and the Y axis are still swapped. I'm using Blender 2.71.

Comment: maybe apply the rotation? Ctrl A > Rotation

Comment: I tried Ctrl + A + R, and Ctrl + R, but that doesn't change the coordinations.

Comment: could you please share your file (upload and share the URL): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I'm not using a specific .blend file. Even at the start up with the cube and light, the coordinates are still switched.

Comment: IIRC, 2.71 still had a preference that allowed that; but it's been a long time.

Comment: So I can manually swap the coordinates in 2.71?

Comment: Is there any way I can revert Z and Y back to their original coordinates?